# GridView Videos Android Studio(Java)

Tags: java, android

Quiero mostrar varios videos en un GRIDVIEW(sin reproducirlos) solo  quiero que se muestren sus miniaturas pero sale el video color negro(miniatura).

Adaptador:

```
package com.example.myapplication.Adaptadores;
```

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.example.myapplication.R;

public class GaleriaVideosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;


public GaleriaVideosAdapter(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    VideoView videoView = new VideoView(mContext);
    //videoView.setVideoPath("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vod0mNv-2O8");
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://64..........xx/vaca.mp4"));
    videoView.setLayoutParams(
            new GridView.LayoutParams(
                    340,
                    350
            ));
    return videoView;
}
```

}

Main:

```
package com.example.myapplication;
```

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.myapplication.Adaptadores.GaleriaImagenesAdapter;
import com.example.myapplication.Adaptadores.GaleriaVideosAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
GridView gridViewImagenes;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   // gridViewImagenes = findViewById(R.id.grid_view_imagenes);
    //gridViewImagenes.setAdapter(new GaleriaImagenesAdapter(this));


    gridViewImagenes = findViewById(R.id.grid_view_imagenes);
    gridViewImagenes.setAdapter(new GaleriaVideosAdapter(this));



}
```

}

Lo he probado con varios videos y youtube tambien y es el mismo resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Podrías agregar como lo intentaste para los videos? :D

Comment: Adaptador Videos:

Comment: GaleriaVideosAdapter no se encuentra en tu pregunta, deberìas agregarlo si lo que deseas es cargar videos

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres visualizar el video y lo tienes descargado, puedes agregarlo a la carpeta raw. Para crear esta carpeta puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Crear la carpeta raw dentro de la carpeta res y ahi agregar tu video.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, para cargar tu video en tu método `getView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    VideoView videoView = new VideoView(mContext);
    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(convertView.getContext());
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName +"/"+R.raw.video1);
    videoView.setLayoutParams(
            new GridView.LayoutParams(
                    340,
                    350
            ));
    mediacontrol.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.stopPlayback();               
        videoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri); 
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        videoView.start();
    return videoView;
}
```

Recomendación: Si deseas visualizar videos desde algún endpoint, puedes utilizar la librería de android llamada exoplayer.

Exoplayer -> https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html

Comment: rguzaman en Android 9 la pantalla se queda en negro(sin thumbail) y luego sale un mensaje de error sin que yo haga nada: No se puede reproducir el ideo

Comment: Puede que sea un error con el ADV. Tendrias que agregar un poco de detalle. aquí te dejo un enlace -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882785/cant-play-this-video-error-using-url-with-videoview-and-mediacontroller